# Using Protractor to select elements with by.repeater()

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e

Using the following Protractor `element` and `by.repeater()` API methods below:

```
var targetRowText = 'Sales';
var targetGridName = 'myGrid';
var sel = 'grid-directive[grid-name="' + targetGridName + '"] .col-freeze .grid-wrapper';
var gridRows = element(by.css(sel).all(by.repeater('row in vm.sourceData.data'));
var result = gridRows.all(by.cssContainingText('span', targetRowText)).first();
```

I am able to select the following row element from a grid which I have labeled, `myGrid`:

```html
<div id="rowId_21" ng-class-odd="'row-2'" ng-class-even="'row-3'" ng-class="vm.hideRow(row)" class="row-3 height-auto">
 <div ng-repeat="column in  vm.sourceData.columns" >
     <div ng-if="!column.subCols" class="ng-scope"> 
  <div ng-if="row[column.field].length !== 0" class="ng-scope highlight21"> 
      <span ng-bind-html="row[column.field] | changeNegToPrenFormat" vm.highlightedrow="" class="ng-binding"> 
                Sales
            </span>
  </div>
     </div>    
 </div>
</div>
```

Please note that I have used `by.cssContainingText()` to look up the "Sales" `span` element.

***MY PROBLEM:***

That that I have located this row in var `result`, how can I retrieve the `id` attribute of that outer-most div ?

In other words, I need to selected `<div id="rowId_21"` so that I can reuse  `id="rowId_21"` in a subsequent Protractor selector.

In jQuery, for example, I could use brute force to get that outer div id as follows :

```
var el = $('grid-directive[grid-name="Sales"] .col-freeze .grid-wrapper #rowId_21 span')
el.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
```

Here's a high-level outlines of what I mean. The grid actually separates the left-most column from the actual data rows, so there are two distinct divs that accomplish this:

```
<div grid-directive grid-name="myGrid">
 <div class="col-freeze" >
    <!-- CONTAINS LEFT-MOST "CATEGORIES" COLUMN -->
 </div>
 <div class="min-width-grid-wrapper"> 
    <!-- CONTAINS THE DATA ROWS-->
 </div>
```

However, I'm struggling to do this in Protractor.

Advice is appreciated...

Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straight-forward option would be to get to the desired parent element using the [`ancestor` axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/ancestor):

```
element(by.xpath("./ancestor::div[starts-with(@id, 'rowId')]")).getAttribute("id").then(function (parentId) {
    // use parentId here
});
```

Though, I think that this going down and then up the tree should be considered as a sign that you are not approaching the problem in an easy and correct way.

Comment: Indeed. I have a grid which has one parent `div` and two `divs` below that. The first div is the left-most "frozen" column of Categories. The second div represents the actual data rows. So when I searched for `"Sales"` in the categories column, I don't have the actual data yet. So I need to traverse back up and down again. Make sense ?

Comment: @bob.mazzo yeah, I understand that the structure of the grid does not make it easy to work with. Have you considered, may be, using `filter()` to filter the `gridRows` by the column name ("Sales" in your case)? I think that might lead to a cleaner solution..

Comment: you know, I came across `by.xpath()` the other day, and also read that it was not recommended in Protractor. However, I will say that in this edge case - you nailed it ! +1

Comment: @bob.mazzo yeah, if you need to get to the parent, XPath is pretty much okay to have. I personally think this style guide rule to forbid xpath locators is overstated, too strong of a recommendation cause, clearly, there are perfectly valid use cases. Thanks!

Comment: I gotta throw a case of beer your way, man. You really came thru for me on mult occasions...not kidding. :-)

Comment: @bob.mazzo likewise, I can throw you a beer(s) for the multiple good questions!